# How can I change the data value of a Vue app from a method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, properties, navbar, display

I have this method, which I use for authentication and I want to change the Navbar of my site to a child component, when the user is logged in. For this I should be able to change my data() value, but it seems impossible.

```
<template>
        <div id="navbar">
          <component v-bind:is='component'></component>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import auth_mixin from '../mixins/auth_mixin.js'
import NavbarLoggedOut from '@/components/navbar_children/NavbarLoggedOut.vue'
import NavbarLoggedIn from '@/components/navbar_children/NavbarLoggedIn.vue'
import NavbarAdmin from '@/components/navbar_children/NavbarAdmin.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Navbar',
  components: {
    'loggedout':NavbarLoggedOut,
    'loggedin':NavbarLoggedIn,
    'admin':NavbarAdmin
  },
  mixins: [auth_mixin],
  created () {
    this.checkIfLoggedIn()
  },
  data() {
    return{
      component:''
    }
  },
  methods: {
      async checkIfLoggedIn () {
            var result = null;
            var token = this.getCookie("token")
            var jsonData = {}
            jsonData["token"] = token
            var bodyFormData = new FormData();
            bodyFormData.append('data', JSON.stringify(jsonData));
            await axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'backend/index.php?action=checkAuth',
                    data: bodyFormData,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                      console.log(response);
                      if(response.data.status==="OK"){
                        this.component="loggedin"
                      }else{
                        this.component="loggedout"
                      }
                    })
                    .catch(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to do this correctly or would you guys recommend another solution for implementing different components, once the user has logged in?

Answer (score 0):

The Vue instance `this` won't work inside normal functions that you're using as callback. That might be the issue in the code. You can either use an arrow function for callback or declare a variable outside assigning the `this` to the variable, and can use the variable inside the function.

Please check the below code for both solutions

> Using an arrow function

```
async checkIfLoggedIn() {
    var result = null;
    var token = this.getCookie("token")
    var jsonData = {}
    jsonData["token"] = token
    var bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('data', JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'backend/index.php?action=checkAuth',
        data: bodyFormData,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data.status === "OK") {
                this.component = "loggedin"
            } else {
                this.component = "loggedout"
            }
        })
        .catch((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

> Declaring another variable for `this`

```
        async checkIfLoggedIn() {
            var result = null;
            var token = this.getCookie("token");
            var jsonData = {};
            jsonData["token"] = token;
            var bodyFormData = new FormData();
            let vue = this;
            bodyFormData.append('data', JSON.stringify(jsonData));
            await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'backend/index.php?action=checkAuth',
                data: bodyFormData,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.data.status === "OK") {
                        vue.component = "loggedin"
                    } else {
                        vue.component = "loggedout"
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
        }
```